# Cancelling HttpConnection.ConnectionCloseReadStream.Read

Tags: .net, http, httpclient

To give some context, I'm executing an HTTP request to which the response is expected to be a stream. Therefore, I use a `StreamReader` on top of the returned stream from the `HttpResponseMessage`.

Simplest scenario

```cs
using ( var streamReader = new StreamReader( await httpClient.GetStreamAsync( url, ct ) ) )
{
    while ( !streamReader.EndOfStream && !ct.IsCancellationRequested )
    {
        var line = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync( ct );

        Console.WriteLine( line );
    }
}
```

So the thing now is that I have a timeout on that `CancellationToken` but when cancellation is requested, it doesn't do anything. It's common for the `ReadLineAsync` to get "stuck", since data is only transmitted if there's something new. But because a network issue doesn't affect the stream, I added a cancellation request after a certain time has passed.

Again, simplest scenario

```cs
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var ct = cts.Token;

ct.Register( () =>
{
    logger.LogInformation( "Cancellation requested." );
} );
```

Running the application, I can see the cancellation is requested

```
2023-05-03 06:29:10 info: consoleapp[0] Cancellation requested.
```

But the reader doesn't budge.

So I went on to see what the underlying stream type is and it's a `HttpConnection.ConnectionCloseReadStream`. Source can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d7f3f5861714568c8efb01c7337a5a6f565e2d1d/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/ConnectionCloseReadStream.cs).

Looking at the code, doesn't seem like the cancellation token is used when calling the `HttpConnection.ReadAsync` method.

```cs
ValueTask<int> readTask = connection.ReadAsync(buffer);
```

Unsure if this matters, because on top we have

```
CancellationHelper.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(cancellationToken);
```

But the reality, is that it's not really working.

Does anyone have any insights on this?

Answer (score 1):

In the example that you provided (SocketsHttpHandler's HttpConnection), CancellationTokens have to be passed down the execution pipe in order for cancellation to properly work, and there were several fixes in that area.
( e.g. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/40715, https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/686 )

In the HttpConnection specifically, they also use CancellationTokens to register actions to tear down the connection (which, in some cases, exempt from passing the token further down the execution pipe)